# Check task scheduled status

Tags: java, spring

I have this config:

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1" />

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler" >
      <task:scheduled ref="taskUpload" method="run" cron="${upload.cron}" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

How I can check status of this task (running or not) from my Java code? Is it posible?

Comment: some options: logging, jmx/mbean, instrumentation.

Comment: If you do it programmatically  yes, xml - don't think so. As far as you can get reference to scheduled task you are good